# weird output from unicodeplots()

Tags: julia

```
using Plots
unicodeplots()
lineplot(1:2)
```

My code is as above, and I expect the output would be a line, but my output is:
[image]

How to get a real plot?

Comment: Maybe not use `unicodeplots` then? Looks like an approximation of a line made of unicode characters to me.

Answer (score 3):

the output shape depends on the font used in your terminal, as noted in the [UnicodePlots](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/UnicodePlots.jl) documentation in the `known Issues` part, it is recommended to use the [juliaMono](https://juliamono.netlify.app/) font to get the intended shape and resolution.

if you cannot control the font of your console, the package has different kinds of canvases which can solve your issue, such as using an ASCII `DotCanvas` or `AsciiCanvas` to be able to render the output correctly in `cmd.exe` (with  a slightly worse resolution).

```
using Plots
unicodeplots()
lineplot(1:2, canvas=DotCanvas)
```

[image]

you can read more about the canvases available in the `Low-level interface` part of the documentation.